# How to capture facebook "unlike" event?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-like, facebook-social-plugins

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
    function(response) {
        alert ('liked!')
   }
);
```

How do I check the reverse action?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is `edge.remove` event that may be used in a similar way

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.remove',
  function(response) {
    alert ('unliked!')
  }
);
```

Comment: is it normal that it takes some seconds to be called (both on creat and remove) ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean:

```
var handleResponse = function(response) {
   alert ('You unliked the URL: ' + response);
};
FB.Event.unsubscribe('edge.create', handleResponse);
```

Ref: [Event.unsubscribe](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.unsubscribe/)

Comment: I'm almost sure that OP had something other in mind and the question title and wording completely confusing. ;)